# Uninstall Windows and Install Elementary Freya OS, cause unbootable OS

Tags: boot, elementary-os, reboot

I've already uninstalled my Windows and installed Elementary Freya OS. But then my laptop won't reboot. It said "Reboot and select proper boot device ..."

Here is the complete specification of my laptop : [complete specifications](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10920061/)

Did this happen because I haven't turned off my EFI mode via the Windows 8 setting before I removed the Windows OS? If it was so, then how can I set it off directly from the BIOS?

** my laptop type is asus a450c

Comment: My guess is that you didn’t write a bootloader, or it didn’t write correctly. (I’ve been in both of those situations many times.) Can you boot to your installed OS with a boot disk?

Comment: @yellowantphil i'm not sure how can i write a bootloader. do you mind to tell me how can i do that? I installed my OS with a usb stick.

Comment: Check your OS documentation to see if it says anything about installing GRUB. You might be able to boot into your OS using the install discs too. There could be a “boot to existing OS” option.

Answer (score 0):

Here are things that I've tried to install Elementary OS Freya on a UEFI PC/laptop.

1. I tried to find the UEFI setting in the BIOS mode after I've done installing the eOS, but I can't find any setting on this asus. - **failed**.
2. I created partitions for `/boot` and `/` separately and try to installed the eOS again, but yet it's still **failed**.
3. The last try, I realized that in the installation process, eOS was asking me to add a `/efi` partition which will add some setting in those `/efi` partition. I tried it, but **without internet connection**,the installation process **crash** in the middle of it.
4. I reinstalled once again, creating `/efi`, `/`, `/home` and `swap` partitions and also turning on my internet connection and **it works**!

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you've more or less answered your own question (which is great). For future reference (and the benefit of others who might look at this question), in regard to step 1 in your second post, you can enable changing the UEFI settings in BIOS by creating a UEFI password. Seems a bit odd, but it works.